# How to login a user with custom fileds, let's say with his CNIC number or bloodtype?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I'm new to android and firebase, so let me ask. I'v  an application for Blood Bank, I've done registering user by asking email and password. Also I've verified his phone number and store additional information in Realtime Database.

The real question is, I want the user to log his bloodtype and phone number and if its in the database, he's logged in and save his userID for signing out later.

Sorry for asking a silly question.I'll appreciate if someone help me out here.

Comment: Here's a silly answer: http://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write

Comment: Maybe you can find some more information if you look for logging in with a username. I have seen a couple questions about that before and that sounds simular.